# What book features a kid who becomes a swashbuckler in a MMORPG?

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm trying to identify a book. I believe it is about a MMORPG game. A kid gets into the game, makes his character a swashbuckler, and gets a rare item right in the beginning of it.

Comment: When did you read this novel? Do you know when it might have been published, and in what country? Do you remember anything about the cover, any character, or other details?

Comment: I found the book it is called epic.

Comment: You should probably add that as an answer, and mark it as accepted (tomorrow), so that it can help others in the future.

Comment: If it helps, here's a link to it's wiki page: [Epic (novel)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_%28novel%29)

Answer (score 2):

Per @AustinPazourek's own comment above, the book in question is "[Epic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_%28novel%29)" by Conor Kostick.

> Epic follows the life of a boy named Erik Haraldson and his
>   involvement in a game called Epic. Epic is a virtual game, but is
>   considered by all the inhabitants of New Earth as much more. A generic
>   fantasy game, Epic echoes World of Warcraft and Everquest, but the
>   entire population of New Earth play the game, as its rewards directly
>   affect their income, social standing and careers. Epic is used to
>   control violence, which, in their society, is illegal and is treated
>   with extreme severity. A growing injustice has emerged in the world,
>   as the game of Epic has progressed to a point where, since the game's
>   currency is used as money in the real world, it is nearly impossible
>   for poor people to actually advance in the game, unless given money by
>   those who inherited wealth and powerful equipment, or finding
>   treasures.

[image]